# Can anyone please point me how to use GROUP BY in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by

```
return mDd.query(DATABASE_TABLE,new String[] {
    KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_TITLE,
    KEY_DATAS,
    KEY_BODY,
    KEY_DATE_TIME
},null,null,null,null,null);
```

// here is my code i want to insert to group by KEY_TITLE but i cant find the right syntax, can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead if the third null just insert KEY_TITLE, that should do the trick